# Getting Issue Using Excel 14.0 DLL in c# 2010

Tags: c#, excel, dll

> I m getting the following issue when i try to build my C#
>   Application. i want to export the data into Office 2010 or 2007. The
>   error is as Follow

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
     failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

Comment: There is some alternative good solution for export to excel using exceldatareader.codeplex.com

Comment: Could you please provide some Code? It seems that you forgot to add some assemblys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the struggle of 3 to 4 hours , i find the solutions about the above issue. The issue was that i was adding the reference of COM rather then .net.
When i add .net excel reference then this issue solved.
Any way, i have all thing installed PIA and my machine is x86.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a build related error, you'll only get it when trying to *run* your program.  The two most common reasons for getting it:

- you don't have Office installed on your machine
- you've got a 64-bit version of Windows and the EXE project targets AnyCPU

The workaround for the latter mishap is to right-click your EXE project, Properties, change the Platform Target setting to "x86".  If you actually have the 64-bit version of Office 2010 installed then do the opposite, change x86 to AnyCPU.